# HTML/CSS Blink Animation Website

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a flashing effect for an image and I've come across that you can use "Blink" Animations. But I'm clueless on how to set a time limit e.g. Flash on and Off in 4 seconds.

I have used Keyframe (blink) with opacity on different percentage.

Is there any chance you guys could help me it would be much appreciated.

Here is my code that I have tried.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /* Firefox old*/
    
    @-moz-keyframes blink {
      10% {
        opacity: 90;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 80;
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
      10% {
        opacity: 90;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 100;
      }
    }
    /* IE */
    
    @-ms-keyframes blink {
      10% {
        opacity: 60;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 80;
      }
    }
    /* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
    
    @keyframes blink {
      10% {
        opacity: 60;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 80;
      }
    }
    
    .blink-image {
      -moz-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;
      /* Firefox */
      -webkit-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;
      /* Webkit */
      -ms-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;
      /* IE */
      animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;
      /* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p align="center">
    <img class="blink-image" src="images/GetOrderTimeForChristmas.jpg" width="390" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I am unable to understand the question but, have you tried changing`animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out` to `animation: blink normal 4s infinite ease-in-out` i.e., change in animation duration

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that I though it was a REM Statment.

Comment: You can also use `opacity` 0 to 1 instead of 60, 80 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note here is: The **opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0**. The lower value, the more transparent

IE8 and earlier use **filter:alpha(opacity=x)**. The x can take a value from 0 - 100. A lower value makes the element more transparent.
I have made the changes to your code and you can find the snippet below.

Hope it works!

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Firefox old*/
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from, 50%, to {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  25%, 75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
} 

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from, 50%, to {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  25%, 75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/* IE */
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    from, 50%, to {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  25%, 75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
} 
/* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
@keyframes blink {
    from, 50%, to {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  25%, 75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
} 
.blink-image {
    -moz-animation: blink normal 4s infinite ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: blink normal 4s infinite ease-in-out; /* Webkit */
    -ms-animation: blink normal 4s infinite ease-in-out; /* IE */
    animation: blink normal 4s infinite ease-in-out; /* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p align="center">
<img class="blink-image" src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" width="390" />
</body>
</html>
javascript jquery html css
shareeditflag
```